# Unix fork: how many processes are created?

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, fork

Hi I am doing exercises on Operating System Concepts 9th Edition Chapter 3, there is a "how many processes are created including the parent process?" question confusing me. The code is in C with Unix system call, fork():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){

fork();
fork();
fork();

return 0;
}
```

How any buddy answer the question? Thanks

Comment: What's confusing about it? You seem to have figured it out.

Comment: simply process created by fork is 2^n where n=no of fork calls.

Answer (score 2):

```
fork();
```

1st fork created new process from running process(main) . in System now there is two process

```
fork();
```

Each of Both process again calls fork. So two new process created. So total four process is in system now

```
fork();
```

Now Each four process calls fork. so again four new process created. so total eight process is created after last call of fork();

Answer (score 1):

There are total 8 process including parent process.
Here, [image: Number of processes using fork()]

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is 8, like 1 -> 2 -> 4 ->8

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @hkf This answer is from the OP, so I don't think it's a critique or request for clarification. The OP should have included the guess in the question.

Comment: @JimBalter O the manual is wrong! Should be 8! I just tested it! Thanks

Comment: What manual is wrong? 8 is completely consistent with what the Unix/Linux/POSIX manuals say.

Comment: @JimBalter this question is actually from Abraham's 9th edition Operating System Concept book, their official manual solution is written 16 for this question. You can check their website. Great book though.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the word "manual" here. Abraham's book is not a manual.